# How to add propTypes to an unnamed component?

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

I want to provide propTypes for a component that is computed in real time.

Consider the following code:

```js
const Comp = (a, b, c) => (d) => {
    const e = computeABCD(a, b, c, d);
    return <E e={e} />
}

Comp.propTypes = {
   a: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
   b: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
   c: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
}
```

How can I add propTypes to the component that is returned by Comp?

The only way I can think of doing this is creating a named component within the function Comp and setting the PropTypes in there.

Would that be a idiomatic solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least you have to write the component definition somewhere to return. There you can write the proptypes.

```
const Comp = (a, b, c) => (d) => {
    const e = computeABCD(a, b, c, d);
    return <E e={e} />
}

Comp.propTypes = {
   a: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
   b: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
   c: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
}

const E = ({e}) => {
}

E.propTypes = {
 e: PropTypes.string
}
```

Comment: Thanks! There is no idiomatic way to provide propTypes to a component that remains unnamed, right?

Comment: Give me the example of component that remains unnamed so, I can visualize it.

Comment: What I mean is that the solution in this case was to make the unnamed component named. So I am assuming that the idiomatic way is not to return an unnamed component in the first place as I was doing.

Comment: Yes, atleast we required component definition somewhere to use componet and write its proptypes.